# ANgular Directives in a separate JS file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this ngFocused directive working, but I'd like to put it into its own js file. How would I wire that up?

```
    var appObject = angular
        .module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
        .directive('ngFocused', [
            function() {
                var FOCUS_CLASS = "focused";
                return {
                    restrict: 'A', //Attribute only
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                        ctrl.$focused = false;
                        element.bind('focus', function(evt) {
                            element.addClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
                            scope.$apply(function() { ctrl.$focused = true; });
                        }).bind('blur', function(evt) {
                            element.removeClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
                            scope.$apply(function() { ctrl.$focused = false; });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Comment: Keep the main module by itself (`angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]);`), and then in the directive's file, use `angular.module("app").directive("ngFocused", ...`. There's no reason to store the module in a variable and share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i like the IIFE approach.  In your new file:

```
(function(app) {

     app.directive(....)

}(angular.module('app'));
```

That'll keep all your objects out of the global namespace.  Be sure to reference your script defining your angular app before one's that reference it.

Comment: Oh no. I'm definitely going to have to steal this and start using it.

Comment: I only stole the idea from [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/03/17/building-better-models-for-angularjs.aspx) myself

Comment: I love it no matter where it came from. I mean, I use the IIFE approach everywhere. But I never passed the module to the IIFE - I usually pass jQuery (like you've added), window, or something like that. But a change so simple as this seems so much better to me

Answer (score 1):

Just split them into two files. (And don't forget to reference the new file to your html file using the `<script>` tag):

```
// file app.js
var appObject = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

// file ngFocused.js
appObject.directive('ngFocused', [ function() {
    var FOCUS_CLASS = "focused";
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //Attribute only
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$focused = false;
            element.bind('focus', function(evt) {
                element.addClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
                scope.$apply(function() { ctrl.$focused = true; });
            }).bind('blur', function(evt) {
            element.removeClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
            scope.$apply(function() { ctrl.$focused = false; });
        })
     };
}]);
```